# Configure Artifactory to live at http://some.domain:port instead of http://some.domain:port/artifactory/

Tags: docker, docker-compose, artifactory

I am running the latest version of Artifactory OSS by means of docker-compose (as explained [here](http://jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+with+Docker) and demonstrated [here](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-docker-examples/blob/master/docker-compose/artifactory-oss.yml)). My docker-compose file looks something like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  artifactory:
    image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
    container_name: artifactory
    ports:
      - 3101:8081
    volumes:
     - artifactory5_data:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
#    environment:
#     - EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx4g
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 32000
        hard: 40000

volumes:
  artifactory5_data:
```

What I want to change is the path at which Artifactory is available. Currently it is `http://sub.domain.tld:3101/artifactory` but I would like to shorten that to `http://sub.domain.tld:3101`.
Ideally I'd like to achieve this by only changing the docker-compose file or environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow instructions detailed in [JFrog knowledge base](https://www.jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-setup-artifactory-to-run-as-the-root-application-in-tomcat/).

Since you are using Docker, I suggest you build your own Docker image based on the official **docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest** image with the needed manipulations done as suggested in the article.

```
FROM docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest

# Do your manipulations here
```

**Note** - always prefer using a specific version rather than `latest`. This way you have complete control of your deployment.